# Is there no such thing as OCR-B font in bold?

Tags: fonts

I have been looking for a good monospace font in order to meet the criteria of a client.

One I found that I think has suitable qualities is [OCR-B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCR-B).

However, as near as I can tell, it only comes in "regular" form, no bold or italics.

Is this because its roots as an optically recognizable font precluded variants?

Or is it just that my Google-fu is weak and I simply haven't found it (I think I can claim to have met a reasonable level of requirement of having searched before asking).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty sure you're right with "its roots as an optically recognizable font precluded variants".

You should be able to able to apply faux-bold in most applications, though. While this is normally very bad practice, I wonder if it might produce acceptable results with a font this basic?

Comment: It's not just its roots, its entire purpose is to be optically readable (but more attractive and less machine-like than OCR-A). By definition, a slanted or bold variant would not be OCR.

Comment: I think the verdict is in... no such thing as a bold OCR-B, especially considering @AlanGilbertson's comment. I will look into options for making custom alterations.

Comment: @AlanGilbertson In what sense would a slanted or bold version not be optically readable?

Comment: It would be readable, I'm sure, but it was simpler to make one readable font. Technology wasn't as sophisticated at the time OCR-B was invented.

Answer (score -1):

Quick google on "ocr bold light font"

( http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&biw=1119&bih=692&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=ocr+bold+light+fonts&oq=ocr+bold+light+fonts&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e )

brings up `OCR A Tribute` ( http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/ocr-a-tribute/ )

Comment: Yeah... OCR A and OCR B are very, very different.