# Fonts for styling a blog that includes lots of code samples

Tags: website-design, fonts, resource-recommendations

I'm trying to style a personal site that includes many code listings, with text commentary; many of the code samples are written in the Python language, so they look best a fixed-width font.

There are lots of explanations around on how to choose matching fonts, but I was able to find none that addresses the question of how to make a font stack that includes a good monospace font to be used extensively.  (My personal liking is for "book-like" designs using serif fonts, e.g. [Moargh's theme "Feijoa"](http://moargh.de/wp-content/downloads/wp-themes/feijoa/), but I find it hard to find a [monospace that matches.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5650/do-all-monospace-sans-serif-fonts-look-the-same))

Can you please suggest:

- examples of good web design that includes non-trivial amounts of displayed code, or
- advice or resources on how to proceed for the selection.

Comment: I would say, use this and don't worry about the font too much http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/ ( It includes quite a few themes in the package. )

Answer (score 1):

A list of fonts available on various platforms. Includes lots of monospaced fonts:

[Matrix of fonts bundled with Mac and Windows, Microsoft Office and Adobe Creative Suite](http://media.24ways.org/2007/17/fontmatrix.html)

You'll notice that you actually don't have that many options though. Unless you use TypeKit or embed the font on your page (and use CSS @font-face). Creating a font stack is fairly easy. Here's some advice on it:

[Guide to CSS Font Stacks: Techniques and Resources](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/22/complete-guide-to-css-font-stacks/)

I really like the LESS website. Contains lots of code examples.

[lesscss.org](http://lesscss.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Use Gist from Github - https://gist.github.com/ then it will not only look nice but it'll format it with colors and such like an IDE